# iBeacon: didRangeBeacons is not getting called when running app

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, locationmanager, ibeacon

I prepared all the necessary stuff to setup a beacon region:

```
// Create a NSUUID with the same UUID as the broadcasting beacon
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"];
//raspberry pi:E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0
//estimote:B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D

// Setup a new region with that UUID and same identifier as the broadcasting beacon
self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                                identifier:@"monaLisaBeacon"];

// Tell location manager to start monitoring for the beacon region
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
```

However, didRangeBeacons is not always invoked. It invokes only once but then stops getting invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `didRangeBeacons` was invoked even once? It will not be invoked if you just call `startMonitoringForRegion`. When you call `startMonitoringForRegion` you should get callback in your locationManager's delegate object in the form of `didDetermineState`, `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` . What you need to do is, in your `didEnterRegion` method, call `startRangingBeaconsInRegion`. Here is an example:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;

        //now start ranging
        [_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
    }
}
```

Also dont forget to stop ranging:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;

        //STOP ranging
        [_locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
    }
}
```

Only if you start ranging, your `didRangeBeacons` will be invoked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
// Create a NSUUID with the same UUID as the broadcasting beacon
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"];
//raspberry pi:E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0
//estimote:B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D

// Setup a new region with that UUID and same identifier as the broadcasting beacon
self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                                identifier:@"monaLisaBeacon"];

// Tell location manager to start monitoring for the beacon region
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
```

You need to start ranging beacons as well to make didRangebeacons to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only seeing this with your Raspberry Pi-based beacon?  If so, your Pi's advertisements may be getting turned off by another device attempting to connect with it.  [The Knock app for OSX is known to cause this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252587/raspberry-pi-ibeacon-connection-timing-out), although other apps may do it, too.

If this is the problem, there is a fix documented in an edit to the [blog post](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/09/how-to-make-an-ibeacon-out-of-a-raspberry-pi.html) telling you how to build an iBeacon out of a Raspberry Pi.  You need to edit the iBeacon start script on the Pi to change this line:

```
sudo hciconfig $BLUETOOTH_DEVICE leadv 0
```

to:

```
sudo hciconfig $BLUETOOTH_DEVICE leadv 3
```

Alternatively, you can try simply shutting off whatever app is running that is trying to establish a Bluetooth LE connection to the Raspberry Pi.  If you don't know what app is doing that, though, this may be hard.